# Display mysql data in HTML Table - Latest entry to be shown @ top of table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a requirement to display mysql data in HTML Table -

But the latest entry that is inserted to mysql is to be shown @ top of html table

I have some code, that is used to display mysql data in HTML table,but I find that the data is appended to the end of the table, each time it is executed.

Comment: `.. ORDER BY ???? ...`

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing your query?

Comment: Do you want to completely reverse the order or do you just want the last item to show up as the first entry?

Comment: just add four word in your query ORDER BY ID DESC, instead of pasting so much word on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much data you are planning to show. I'll start with the most general technique, and probably the simplest - make sure your data includes a time added.

Then your query is

```
select * from table_name order by time_added desc
```

Adapt it - table name, column names, what to select... Desc is for descending or you can use asc.

To display, loop as usual, to only display the first few results, limit the query as usual.

If for some reason you can't do that, the alternative is to set up the display in the reverse order. It isn't the best - but knowing you don't have to display the results as they come out is always good.

To do this, you don't change your query, the data comes out in reverse order, and you then loop through it but prepare the display backwards:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
$display = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $display = $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] + "<br>" + $display;
}
echo $display;
```

As I said, I think it's not the best technique, but there's a good thing in this example: don't echo as you loop. Prepare a result, then echo it at the end. It gives you more flexible control over the display.

Comment: Thanks it works so cool; I used this query select * from table_name order by time_added desc... Also I have another query to complicate things, I have the forum home page where data is displayed in a table. If the n/o rows actually exceed 100, then I want to have a next button and show a table in next page.

Comment: In mySQL there is a clause "limit" to get a set number of results, that should help with your paging.